# Why are values in the OpenJDK implementation of HashMap (and other classes) initialized using bitshifts?

Tags: java

I was looking at OpenJDK's [implementation of HashMap](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) and stumbled upon this line of code where the default initial capacity is set:

```java
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 1 << 4; // aka 16
```

Why is a bitshift used here instead of just initializing `DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY` with `16`? I've looked at other classes like [Arrays](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java) and there, too, a value is initialized with a bitshift:

```java
private static final int MIN_ARRAY_SORT_GRAN = 1 << 13;
```

Is it a conventional thing or is it more important for someone working with these implementations to know which binary number the values are instead of the decimal representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because sometimes it's easier to reason with number of bits, rather than numerical ranges. In the case of `HashMap`, however, another reason is that you need to do `hash % numberOfBuckets`, the modulo operation is expensive, so to fasten up one can use a power of two, then modulo may be replaced with logical AND - it'll do the same, but works that way only for powers of two. The `Arrays` case - may be similar reasons.

Comment: "Because sometimes it's easier to reason with number of bits, rather than numerical ranges." Can you give an example for this?

Comment: @tim-kt Anything bitwise really (like bitmasks), and they're easier to understand (65536 vs `1 << 16`).